# ItunesConnect, App will be removed from store if I don't send an updated version

Tags: app-store-connect

I just received an e-mail from Apple saying that one of my app will be removed from the store if I don't provide an updated version of it:

> Dear Developer,
>
> On September 1, 2016, we announced that we’re implementing an ongoing
>   process of evaluating and removing apps that no longer function as
>   intended, don’t follow current review guidelines, or are outdated.
>
> We noticed that your app has not been updated in a significant amount
>   of time.

The problem is that I don't have any update to do for the app but I want to keep it on the store. Will just send the latest version of the app without updates be enough for Apple or do I actually need to add new content to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your apps complies with the latest review guidelines this should not be a problem. Just make sure that it runs on the latest devices and you update metadata and screenshots on iTunes Connect.